# Angular- Got an error while creating routes in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new on Angular and  I want to create routes in my angular app and I got an error in app.module.ts while declaring routes service. I'm getting confused about what I write in the brackets of RouterModule.forRoot()

```
error: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Routes'.RouterModule.forRoot(Routes)
```

route.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ParentComponent } from '../parent/parent.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child.component';

const appRoutes:Routes=[

  {path:"parent",component:ParentComponent},
  {path:"child",component:ChildComponent}
]
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutesService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
// import {MessageserviceService} from './services/messageservice.service'
import {MessageserviceService} from './services/messageservice.service';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent/parent.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';
import { RoutesService } from './services/routes.service';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ParentComponent,
    ChildComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)  //i got error in this line, 
    

  ],
  providers: [MessageserviceService,RoutesService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You might need to also import AppRoutes here..

Comment: @MikeOne where? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Move this declaration

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

  {path:"parent",component:ParentComponent},
  {path:"child",component:ChildComponent}
]
```

to the `AppModule`. Also, seems like you can simply remove `RoutesService`, I don't think it serves any function.

Comment: yes, if I add appRoutes in app.module.ts then it works, but I want to separate routes from my other files/folder that's why I created services, but I don't know how do I create paths using services.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to separate routes from main Module, just create a routingModule as it is done in angular documentation: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-the-approutingmodule

By the way, your code just cannot work.
If you want to keep "appRoutes" in a service file, then either use

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [

  {path:"parent",component:ParentComponent},
  {path:"child",component:ChildComponent}
];
```

But then your service is just useless.

Or move appRoutes inside your service, and declare it as an attribute of your service.

In both cases, make sure to import appRoutes in AppModule.

But once again, it's not really the way to handle routing in a "regular" angular app.